# Inserting a specific code to make it look like a small thin line

Tags: html, css

I was searching for a specific code that could do the same thing have on my both pictures below.

Inicially, i thought it was a TR element but it doesn't seem to work out. The running snippet showed bellow is similiar to the idea i have on those pictures below as well.

Image : https://i.stack.imgur.com/YvafM.png

Any ideas?

```css
.popular-articles {
    font-family: Source Sans Pro, sans-serif;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.35
}

.popular-articles .popular-cabeca {
    margin: 47px 67px
}

.popular-articles .cabeca-card {
    background-image: linear-gradient(147deg, #2c74c5 0%, #5be5a7 93%, #2af598 100%);
    font-family: Source Sans Pro;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 16px;
    padding: 2rem;
    margin: 0 4rem 0 0;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: end;
    -ms-flex-pack: end;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-box-flex: 0;
    -ms-flex: 0 0 320px;
    flex: 0 0 229px
}


.popular-articles .cabeca-card p {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 14.2px;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 1.2px;
    line-height: 27px;
}

.popular-articles .cabeca-card-title {
    font-size: 32px;
    margin: 0 0 .5rem;
    text-align: right;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: "Source Sans Pro";
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 37px;
}

.popular-articles .cabeca-card-sponsor {
    text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="popular-articles">
        <section class="popular-cabeca cabeca-card white-underline-links">
            <h2 class="cabeca-card-title">
                Próximos<br>Lançamentos
            </h2>
            <p class="cabeca-card-sponsor">FILMES / SÉRIES</p>
        </section >
</div>
```

Image : https://i.stack.imgur.com/YvafM.png

Comment: Do the same thing? Do what thing? Sorry totally no clue what you want man, mind if you could elaborate more?

Comment: @Gosi I totally forgot to add the images.. the post has been edited with the new ones!

Comment: Basically, you want to make a thin line with HTML & CSS ?

Comment: @TomásSilva Ok I've added an answer, please check. its working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add a line, you can use the `::before` property to that particular css class.

What the `::before` does is that, before the content starts, it will do your css code. Same concept for `::after`, it will do after the content.

So in your case, you can add `::before` inline-block element, set a border to it and use margin to lift it up.

Try this:

```css
.popular-articles {
    font-family: Source Sans Pro, sans-serif;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.35
}

.popular-articles .popular-cabeca {
    margin: 47px 67px
}

.popular-articles .cabeca-card {
    background-image: linear-gradient(147deg, #2c74c5 0%, #5be5a7 93%, #2af598 100%);
    font-family: Source Sans Pro;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 16px;
    padding: 2rem;
    margin: 0 4rem 0 0;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: end;
    -ms-flex-pack: end;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-box-flex: 0;
    -ms-flex: 0 0 320px;
    flex: 0 0 229px
}


.popular-articles .cabeca-card p {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 14.2px;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 1.2px;
    line-height: 27px;
}

.popular-articles .cabeca-card-title {
    font-size: 32px;
    margin: 0 0 .5rem;
    text-align: right;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: "Source Sans Pro";
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 37px;
}

.popular-articles .cabeca-card-sponsor {
    text-align: right;
}

.cabeca-card-sponsor::before {
    display: inline-block;
    content: "";
    border-top: 2px solid #ffffff;
    width: 50px;
    margin: 5px 15px 3px 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="popular-articles">
        <section class="popular-cabeca cabeca-card white-underline-links">
            <h2 class="cabeca-card-title">
                Próximos<br>Lançamentos
            </h2>
            <p class="cabeca-card-sponsor">FILMES / SÉRIES</p>
        </section >
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created sample  https://jsfiddle.net/arunsoraba/1oLcqvn5/5/

```
<div class="popular-articles">
        <section class="popular-cabeca cabeca-card white-underline-links">
            <h2 class="cabeca-card-title">
                Próximos<br>Lançamentos
            </h2>
            <p class="cabeca-card-sponsor">
           <span> <span class="lineEle"></span>FILMES / SÉRIES</span></p>
        </section >
</div>



  .lineEle{
  min-width:150px;
  border:1px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
}
.popular-articles {
    font-family: Source Sans Pro, sans-serif;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.35
}

.popular-articles .popular-cabeca {
    margin: 47px 67px
}

.popular-articles .cabeca-card {
    background-image: linear-gradient(147deg, #2c74c5 0%, #5be5a7 93%, #2af598 100%);
    font-family: Source Sans Pro;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 16px;
    padding: 2rem;
    margin: 0 4rem 0 0;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: end;
    -ms-flex-pack: end;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-box-flex: 0;
    -ms-flex: 0 0 320px;
    flex: 0 0 229px
}


.popular-articles .cabeca-card p {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 14.2px;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 1.2px;
    line-height: 27px;
}

.popular-articles .cabeca-card-title {
    font-size: 32px;
    margin: 0 0 .5rem;
    text-align: right;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: "Source Sans Pro";
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 37px;
}

.popular-articles .cabeca-card-sponsor {
    text-align: right;
}
```